# How to make Flask work again after changing its original location

Tags: python, shebang

Basically, I installed Flask in one of my directories(/home/effay/cs196), later moved the directory(/home/effay/cs196) to somewhere else(/home/effay/project), and changed its name from "cs196" to "api".

Now, in a virtual environment, whenever I try to run Flask by using a command "flask run", I get the following error:

```
bash: /home/effay/project/api/venv/bin/pip: /home/effay/cs196/venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I read some similar issues posted online and assume I should find a way to edit the shebang line to point to the correct location, which I honestly am not sure if it's the right approach. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is nothing to do with Flask. You moved your virtual environment and broke it

Comment: Yup, a lot! I just removed the broken venv and made a new one. Thank you